# Computing conditional probabilities on multivariate data from covariances

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, covariance, marginal-distribution

I am struggling to implement some Bayesian algorithm which I hope you may help me with.

I am required to compute all probabilities of the form:

$$P(Z_i\le z_i\;|\;Z_1=z_1, \dots, Z_{i-1}=z_{i-1}) \;\; \textrm{for }i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$$

The $n$ components of $Z$ are marginally standard normals, and $R$ is the correlation matrix, which I presume is required to compute the conditional probabilities.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming joint normality, first obtain the joint distribution of $Z_1,..,Z_i$ by just extracting $i\times i$ section of your covariance matrix; your mean vector is full of $0$'s due to standard normality of marginals. Now, you should have $f(z_1,z_2,...,z_i)$.

Then, Use the decomposition in [Conditional Distributions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Conditional_distributions) section of the MV Gaussian wiki entry, to obtain the PDF of $Z_i$ given $Z_1,..,Z_{i-1}$, i.e. $f(z_i|z_{1\_\_\_i-1})$. This is going to be normal, with some $\mu,\sigma$.

Finally, either use numeric integration, some library function or a Z table to calculate $P(X\leq z_1)$, where $X$ is normally distributed wrt $\mu,
\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference to the block approach. Given that my conditioned variable is x_i (last one in the list), can I obtain a similar direct expression for \bar\my  and \bar\Sigma without having to reorder the variables? Like finding the Schur complement for the conditioning variables as described in the wiki? TIA

Comment: @bizkotxoa yes you can.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were briliant.

Comment: @bizkotxoa if you think the answer is ok for you, can you answer and/or upvote the answer?

Comment: Just marked the green tick thing. As for voting, I tried before, but was unable due to me being a newcomer. Anything else I can do?